# Not able to get the appsetting value for Azure Key Vault secrets in asp.net 6 MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I am using the Azure key vault secret using Managed Identity and using ASP.Net 6 (core). I have implemented the logic and able to get the secret but I am not able to read it back from appsetting.json file.   I debug the file and able to see my secret that I have created. See the below code that I am using to get the key value secret and retrieve key/value from appsettings file.  Please understand I have tried other forums , microsoft document and questions asked in stackoverflow but I am unable to find the solution.

See the code below:

SecretName: kv-secret

SecretValue: "myconnectiongString"

Note that I am able to see the value in program file for following code:

```
var testConfig = app.Configuration["kv-secret"];
```

Getting null for the below line

```
var check4 = appsettings["kv-secret"];
```

**code**

Program file:

```
  builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
  new Uri("https://kv-vault.azure.net/"),
  new DefaultAzureCredential());

  //other code .....
  var app = builder.Build();

  //Check if I am getting a secret value
  var checkSecretValue= app.Configuration["kv-secret"];  //able to see the value when debug
```

Repository class

```
  public List<string> GetValueFromAppSettingJsonFile()
     {
         var configuration = new 
         ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", 
        optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        var appsettings=configuration.Build();           
        var check4 = appsettings["kv-secret"];
    }
```

In the above code var check4 shows null, whereas I checked in the program file.

AppSettings.json

I did not add any code in Appsetting.json file but some other settings do exists there. I expect the code should place a code as
"kv-secret":"myConnectionString",   //I don't have any hierarchy.

Comment: Not sure to understand: are you expecting your app settings json file to be updated ? in your repository class, you need to grab existing config, not generating a new config cause your settings are coming from KV not app settings josn file

Comment: Okay, yes I was expecting wrongfully that the code would add the key/value for Key Vault secret in appsettings.  So understand it is not in appsettings then how I can read it from KV from repository class not controller.  Not that it is matter but my Repository is injected from controller class. I am mentioning is because previously I found that IConfiguration can be initialized in the constructor in controller but doing the same in other class I had issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how Options work with secrets. Think of Options as a collation of all the places settings might have been stored (called a Provider). Maybe you have a value in appSettings.json, one in appSettings.Development.json and one in a KeyVault. Options will grab all of them and collate them into one object. If there are duplicates there's a ranking system, but I don't think that's your issue.

In your initial build you are getting the values from all the Providers. In your repository you are only checking one Provider; appSettings.json. If the value is in KeyVault then it's not going to find it.

I'd recommend creating a class of your settings, and injecting that into your repository.

```
public class MySettings 
{
    public string LaunchCodes { get; set; }
}

public class MyRepository
{
    public MyRepository(IOptions<MySettings> settings)
    {
        var setting = settings.Value.LaunchCodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel like I am getting there because my understanding was wrong  that I was searching for KeyValultSecret's secret in appsetting.json.  I tried you solution but I am still getting null.

Comment: You need to do a bit more work to get Options working, like add the Providers in your builder in Startup, and bind to the sections in ConfigureServices. [This article](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/) might help you get it working